# lambda function doesn't work in priority_queue in c++ (when using [&])

Tags: c++, lambda, priority-queue

When I am doing Leetcode.com, the following code cannot be compiled.

```
auto cmp=[&](pair<int,int> a, pair<int,int> b){return heightMap[a.first]
         [a.second]<heightMap[b.first][b.second];};

priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>,decltype(cmp)> pq;
```

It works well when I use

```
auto cmp=[](...){return true;}.
```

But I have to use

```
auto cmp=[&](...){...}
```

because I need to access heightMap in the function.

I don't know why this cannot be compiled

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `[&]` cannot be used at namespace scope; [the code works fine](https://godbolt.org/g/C2w4yf) at block scope

Comment: I don't believe you that a stateless lambda works, it has the same problem as your lambda that captures `heightMap`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Praetorian the `[]` version [is accepted](https://godbolt.org/g/GQFemG), in some contexts at least

Comment: @M.M Because you're not default constructing the `priority_queue`, as the OP is. And what's wrong with capturing at namespace scope?

Comment: @Praetorian [clang reports an error](https://godbolt.org/g/Z6KMVy) , I trusted it but perhaps it is a compiler bug

Comment: @M.M Looks like clang is right - http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#3 And thinking about it, that makes sense because you don't have to capture a global in order to use it within a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working at block scope (i.e. inside a function).

The correct code -- for both the `[&]` and `[]` cases -- should be:

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
//                                                                   ^^^^^
```

You can see this in the [cppreference example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue).

If you think about it, the definition of `pq` with only `decltype(cmp)` can't know about any local variable -- that attachment is only formed in the actual creation of `cmp`.

---

The reason is that the default constructor for `priority_queue` is (C++17 [priqueue.cons]):

```
explicit priority_queue(const Compare& x = Compare(), Container&& y = Container());
```

As you can see, this involves default-constructing an object of type `Compare`. Prior to C++20, [lambdas are not default constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

The default construction of stateless lambdas was added by [P0624](https://wg21.link/p0624) which didn't quite make it into C++17, but does now appear in C++20 drafts.

Technically a C++17 compiler should reject even the `[]` version; but it seems some compilers have made a headstart on C++20 support.

I notice that clang++ 6.0.0 actually allows default construction of a lambda specified as `[&]` when it happens that no variable is actually captured; whereas the wording of P0624 says that that case should be rejected. Perhaps this will change again before C++20 is finalized.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!